# No block available with a module

Tags: 7, panels

I am using [Facebook post module](https://www.drupal.org/project/fb_post) which display its "Fb Account connection" generated informations/options in an user/%uid/edit/fb-post page.

I want to display these outputs in a custom panels page, but the module doesn't provide blocks, views, forms, or nothing I see that I could handle inside panels.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to create a block in your own custom module that displays this info. Take a close look at the `fb_post_page` function in `fb_post.admin.inc` and you can see what the module uses to output that data on the user/%uid/edit/fb-post page.

I'm not super familiar but it looks like the info you want to display can be gotten by calling `theme('fb_post_connect', array('connection_path' => fb_post_get_oauth_url($account, $app_id)));` and displaying the result in a block (or even directly in a panel pane)

Comment: Thank you very much @bleen. As you suggested, I manage this display by creating a block hook in the module file with `$block['content'] = fb_post_page($account)`. Thanks again!